double.Parse returns very different values on different computers
We have a GPS logger app that reads a string of response from Serial port, calculates latitude and longitude and displays them on a label. I used Visual studio 2022 + WPF + .net 8.
The input data format as received by program on both computers, it has fixed-length fields:
$GNGGA,132233.80,5051.22113,N,00542.35312,E,2,12,0.57,52.6,M,46.4,M,,0136*7E
The numbers 5051.22113 and 00542.35312 are Lat/Lon values.
The part of the code that converts them to double:
double latitude, longitude;
if (gps_response_valid == true && gps_response.Contains("$GNGGA") && gps_response.Contains('M'))
{
    int ptr = gps_response.IndexOf("$GNGGA");
    string lat = gps_response.Substring(ptr + 17, 10);
    latitude = double.Parse(lat.Substring(0, 2)) + (double.Parse(lat.Substring(2, 8)) / 60);
    if (gps_response[ptr + 28] == 'S') latitude = -latitude;
    //write_to_log(latitude.ToString());
    string lon = gps_response.Substring(ptr + 30, 11);
    longitude = double.Parse(lon.Substring(0, 3)) + (double.Parse(lon.Substring(3, 8)) / 60);
    //write_to_log(longitude.ToString());
    label_lat_data.Text = latitude.ToString();
    label_lon_data.Text = longitude.ToString();
}

The exact same program on my computer gives my location as 50.853674166666664 and 5.7059495 which is correct (Now you have my real location!).
Running the program on my colleague's computer gives 85420,86666666667 and 70584,81666666667. (note the "," instead of "." as decimal point)

My friend does not have Visual studio installed on his system. I just handed him the whole bin folder net8.0-windows with .exe app in it.
First running the app, windows asked us to install a runtime library and we did, then we could run the program.

My regional format:

My friend's regional format:

So what's the problem here? We have some recorded data and we need to find out what happened to be able to correct the data.

Try double.Parse(str, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).

@GoodNightNerdPride Thanks, do you know how to reverse it? we have recorded data in the other format and we don't know how to fix it.

Same for latitude.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Note that the recorded data should always use the . as decimal separator and the , to separate the values in the command sequence, because that's how the NMEA sentences are defined.

This question is similar to: Why does C# calculate double and decimal numbers wrongly?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

By default, double.Parse uses the currently defined CultureInfo.
Since your configure region is United States, en-US is used as CultureInfo (. as decimal comma).
The configured region of your friend is Netherlands, which means double.Parse (probably) uses nl-NL as CultureInfo and treats , as decimal comma.
To avoid this, you can tell double.Parse to use an independent (invariant) culture by passing CultureInfo.InvariantCulture:
double.Parse(YOUR_STRING, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

CultureInfo.InvariantCulture uses . as a decimal separator and , as a thousands separator.

Double.Parse() by default uses the culture settings from the local system where it runs. Not all cultures use a period as the decimal separator, and there can be other odd formatting quirks as well. You can even customize the cultural settings on your system to make a frankenculture for your own preference.
If your app can run on computers from differing cultures, you have to think carefully about the inputs:

When parsing inputs provided directly by the user of the local computer, the local culture on the computer is still correct.
When parsing inputs provided by a user from a remote computer, you need to check whether there is culture information available to you from that user or their system for parsing the value.
When parsing inputs generated by a machine with a specific culture, you need to know the culture settings used by the machine to generate the value.

As an example of the third option, imagine you work in America for a company based in Germany. You might need to be prepared to parse inputs using the German culture settings, even when running on your local system set in English. More commonly, international organizations will set all their server systems to generate values using a common "invariant" culture. In this way, computers will be able to read those values no matter where they are.
You have this last situation. Your inputs are generated by a GPS device that is likely configured to use the invariant culture. It works on your machine, because your default culture (whether en-US or other) is a close-enough match for this invariant culture, at least in this aspect. But it's not fully "correct" on your machine... it just happens to work well enough by chance. It does not work at all on the other machine, because the default en-NL culture there is NOT a close enough match.
Many English-language developers (especially American) are surprised to learn about this. They become accustom to this special invariant culture closely matching their own, thanks to many large tech companies growing up in California and Seattle. They may not encounter this issue as quickly in their careers. Almost none of us were immune, and for a long time we got away with just using the default culture from our own systems. But we all have to learn about it at some point... usually the hard way; it causes a lot of bugs.
Instead, when reading values, you should think about which situation you have, and (when appropriate) use the .Parse() overload that allows you to specify the invariant (or other) culture:
double.Parse(lon.Substring(0, 3), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Similarly, when outputting numeric values to strings, you should think about  what kind of situation you have. Are you generating numbers for a machine? Force the invariant culture. Are you generating formatted numbers for a person, on the local system? Use the default culture on the system. Are you generating formatted numbers for a person on a remote system? Check if there's a CultureInfo you can use or construct that will match this person's expectation.
For this code, that is the ToString() function, which also has an overload allowing  you to specify a culture. However, we are showing this the local user. It is correct to allow them to see the value in their own preferred format, so the default culture settings on their machine are already correct; there is no need to specify the culture.
The final lesson is this stuff can be complicated. Thanks to these cultural/internationalization issues, converting back and forth between numbers (or dates!) and strings is not the simple operation we might expect. It can be surprisingly complicated, and therefore slow and error-prone; something to avoid. Therefore, the best strategy is typically to parse these values into a real numeric (or date) type early, keep them that way as long as possible, and only convert back to string at the last possible moment before showing to the user or writing for output.
In this situation, that means you want think about whether these values will be written anywhere after they are shown in the textbox. If the user could, say, click a button that would then write them to a database, you want to make sure you also preserve the parsed decimal values, so it is these decimal values you write to the DB instead of re-parsing the string contents from the textbox. And if the user first edits the textbox, you want to parse that to a decimal using their own culture.

Lesson learned, but is there any way to undo this change on a currently recorded data?

If the recorded data uses the comma as list separator as well as decimal separator, then you have a problem. It may still be possible to fix the data with some heuristics, e.g., by counting the separator positions and replacing the right ones with ".".

@OlivierJacot-Descombes Fortunately it uses ";" as list separator. I'm wondering if the NL culture considers comma as decimal point, then why considered the number xxxx.xxxx as a decimal numeral since it should ignore the "dot". The substrings are positioned to contain just the number from original string.

@TirdadSadriNejad There are also group separators and group sizes. That's why you see xxxx.xxxx. But you don't need to worry about that. It's enough to know the values you need to parse are generated by the GPS device, and therefore are likely using the invariant culture. You can specify that when reading the values, and continue to let the program show the the person the value in their own preferred format, whatever that might be.

@OlivierJacot-Descombes The question says the fields are fixed-length, so the , list separator is a convenience and doesn't have to impact parsing.

I doubt it is fixed length. By comparing different examples found online I found lines differing in length. E.g. in the example given in the question the second-last parameter is missing, leading to two consecutive commas.
